# insert records into a table - column as rows based on conditions

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a table - Base_table

```
create table base_table (ID number,FACTOR_1 number,FACTOR_1 number,FACTOR_3 number,FACTOR_4 number,TOTAL number, J_CODE varchar2(10))

insert into base_table values (1,10,52,5,32,140,'M1');
insert into base_table values (2,null,32,24,12,311,'M2');
insert into base_table values (3,12,null,53,null,110,'M3');
insert into base_table values (4,43,45,42,3,133,'M1');
insert into base_table values (5,432,24,null,68,581,'M2');
insert into base_table values (6,null,7,98,null,196,'M1');
```

| ID | FACTOR_1 | FACTOR_2 | FACTOR_3 | FACTOR_4 | TOTAL | J_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 52 | 5 | 32 | 140 | M1 |
| 2 | null | 32 | 24 | 12 | 311 | M2 |
| 3 | 12 | null | 53 | null | 110 | M3 |
| 4 | 43 | 45 | 42 | 3 | 133 | M1 |
| 5 | 432 | 24 | null | 68 | 581 | M2 |
| 6 | null | 7 | 98 | null | 196 | M1 |

I need to insert this data into another table (FCT_T) based on certain criterias.

Also, I am trying to avaoid usage of unpivot as there are several other columns that I need to insert and manage as part of insert.

```
create table fct_t (id number, p_code varchar2(21), p_value number);
```

Logic to use -

Below values are not part of table, but needs to be used (hard-coded) in logic/criteria (perhaps CASE statements) -

| M_VAL | FACT_1_CODE | FACT_2_CODE | FACT_3_CODE | FACT_4_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | R1 | R2 | R3 | R4 |
| M2 | R21 | R65 | R6 | R245 |
| M3 | R1 | R01 | R212 | R365 |

What I need is something similar (or any better approach available) -

```
insert into FCT_T values 
select id, 
case when FACTOR_1>0 and J_CODE = 'M1' then 'R1' end ,
factor_1
from base_table;
```

So far not able to figure out, how I can move factor column as rows, given an ID can have any number of rows from 1 to 4 based on criteria.
Appreciate help here.

Partial final/expected output (FCT_T) -

| ID | P_CODE | P_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R1 | 10 |
| 1 | R2 | 52 |
| 1 | R3 | 5 |
| 1 | R4 | 32 |
| 2 | R65 | 32 |
| 2 | R6 | 24 |
| 2 | R245 | 12 |

Comment: Perhaps I overthought, and believe it can be done using union all - union all the factors into select and then insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table to your codes and then `UNPIVOT` to convert columns into rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO fct_t (id, p_code, p_value)
WITH codes (M_VAL, FACT_1_CODE, FACT_2_CODE, FACT_3_CODE, FACT_4_CODE) AS (
  SELECT 'M1', 'R1',  'R2',  'R3',   'R4'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'M2', 'R21', 'R65', 'R6',   'R245' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'M3', 'R1',  'R01', 'R212', 'R365' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT id, p_code, p_value
FROM   base_table b
       INNER JOIN codes c
       ON (b.j_code = c.m_val)
UNPIVOT (
  (p_code, p_value)
  FOR factor IN (
    (fact_1_code, factor_1) AS 1,
    (fact_2_code, factor_2) AS 2,
    (fact_3_code, factor_3) AS 3,
    (fact_4_code, factor_4) AS 4
  )
)
WHERE p_value IS NOT NULL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=673c9dcc4f6f26f3cb8e3257fdc386b4)*